# $Ay = 0 \implies c^Ty \leq 0$ , how does this occur?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am studying a proof on linear programming. To make it clearer I am giving an exact copy of the first steps.
[image]

**I am stuck at** the step that, after concluding $Ay = 0 $, we assume without loss of generality that $c^T y \leq 0$.
$A, C$ are two matrices that are not related in general (if I am right) so if  $Ay = 0$ **why does that tell us**  that the cost of objective function is at most 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $c^Ty \le 0$ or $c^Ty > 0$.

If it is the first case, then we are done. Suppose not, consider $y_2=-y$, then we have $c^Ty_2 \le 0$.

We still have $x+y_2 \in P$ and $x-y_2 \in P$.

Comment: so it's not like this implication comes naturally from some math property from $Ay = 0$  but rather that we want in our proof a y s.t : $c^Ty \leq 0$ so for any y it will be either y, or -y that satisfies this ? So $Ay = 0 $ plays no role ?

Comment: well, we still want to satisfy $Ay=0$ but ya, the ability to choose such $y$ is WLOG and it seems that $c^Ty\le 0$ is needed for the next step of the proof.